# knockout component parameter handling

Tags: knockout.js, parameter-passing, knockout-components

I just don't seem to understand the following:

I have a html page that uses a knockout component see code below:

HTML:

```
<h2>Home</h2>
<p data-bind='text: message'></p>
<examlist params="list: StartList"></examlist>
```

So passing a parameter to the examlist

In my knockout examlist component viewmodel:

```
define(['knockout', 'text!./examlist.html'], function(ko, templateMarkup) {

function Examlist(params) {
    this.message = ko.observable('Hello from the examlist component!');
    this.typeOfList = params.list;
    console.log(this.typeOfList);
```

I'm getting an error in my console :

**Uncaught ReferenceError: StartList is not defined**

The examlist html tag markup:

```
<h2>examlist</h2>

<p data-bind='text: message'></p>
```

Why is this?

And in my viewmodel can I directly access the params.list for an if statement?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Regards,

Comment: What is this examlist tag? Interesting to know

Comment: i still cant understand your html. Can you post fiddle?

Comment: You use a "StartList" in the HTML but it isn't defined in JS?

Comment: Don't you need a line this.StartList = ko.observableArray(params.list)

Comment: I cant see anything names startList in viewmodel. Please post fiddle

Comment: I was under the impression that params="list: StartList" would pass a parameter value "list" of type string with value "StartList"
So in my viemodel I would be able to access it using if params.list == "StartList".
Is this assumption wrong?

Comment: you could, but you need to populate StartList, before accessing it, maybe thats the problem?

Comment: I'm trying to fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/maniac_1979/nahyyohy/20/

but can't get the basics to work there, sorry for inconvience.

Comment: `list: StartList` will provide your component viewmodel with a parameter named `list`, which references a variable `StartList` defined in the current binding context of the `<examlist> element`. The error means that the binding context does not have a variable called `StartList`. Try this: 1) open the developer console of either Chrome or Firefox on your site 2) go to the Elements panel (Chrome) / Inspector panel (Firefox) 3) press Escape to show the console 4) select the `<examlist params="list: StartList"></examlist>` element to highlight it 5) enter `ko.contextFor($0)` in the console

Comment: I've fixed your fiddle - it didn't work because you didn't include Knockout, and you forgot to call `ko.applyBindings`: http://jsfiddle.net/nahyyohy/24/

Comment: Thanks janfoeh.

The idea here is to reuse the component (examlist) and do different AJAX calls to the server. I was thinking of just sending a parameter like shown in the example and handle it in the viewmodel. I saw steve sanderson do it in https://vimeo.com/97519516, (around minute 27 although with a boolean), But I think you get my idea, right?
How would you approach this?

Comment: If you need to pass in a string just pass in a string : `<examlist params="list: 'StartList'"></examlist>` note the `''` single quotes around the `'StartList'` otherwise KO treats StarList as a property name and you get this exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need viewModel with lists to bind, something like

```
function MainViewModel() {
    this.list1 = [1, 2, 3];
    this.list2 = ["test", "it", "work"];
}

var viewModel = new MainViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Than you can bind params like

```
<examlist params="list: list1"></examlist>
<examlist params="list: list2"></examlist>
```

or just pass array of values explicitly:

```
<examlist params="list: [5, 6, 7]"></examlist>
```

[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/nahyyohy/29/)